# Изменение TextView из Thread(из отдельного файла java)

Tags: android, многопоточность

Создал поток для принятия пакетов данных по bluetooth. Когда все в одном классе, все работает. Хочу сделать отдельный класс ThreadBluetooth.java, который наследуется от Thread, для принятия данных. задача, в том, чтобы после приема пакета данных, обновилась textview. Усложняется все тем, что я еще и использую стандартный шаблон BottomNavigation.(textView в фрагменте home) Но не понимаю, как использовать Handler и runOnUIThread. что я пропустил?

```
//Запуск потока 
ThreadDataStream threadDataStream = new ThreadDataStream(bluetoothSocket);
threadDataStream.setDaemon(true);
threadDataStream.start();

//тут класс без конструктора(думаю он здесь не нужен)

public class ThreadDataStream extends Thread {


public void run() {
        Handler mhandler = new Handler();

        //Прием данных
        while (true) {

            try {
                buffer = new byte[1];
                bytes = connectedInputStream.read(buffer);
                recieve_string = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                StringBuilder recieve_stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();
                recieve_stringbuilder.append(recieve_string);
                endOfLineIndex = recieve_stringbuilder.indexOf("\r\n");

                if(endOfLineIndex>0) {
                    string_print = recieve_string.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);
                    recieve_stringbuilder.delete(0, endOfLineIndex);
                }

                mhandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        homeFragment.temperature.setText("asd");
                    }
                });


            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Ты `Handler` неправильно создал, посмотри здесь, как привязать его к UI потоку https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui#java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для полноценной работы в другом потоке с возвратом результатов вам понадобится описать коллбэк (callback - обратный вызов), уже после срабатывания которого вы переходите в основной поток (main-thread).

Вот рабочий пример на базе Activity, но ничто не мешает сделать аналогично во фрагменте.

// 1. Класс для выполнения тяжёлой задачи, наследуемый от Thread. Он включает в себя описание результирующего коллбека (интерфейс IDataStreamCallback) с единственным методом dataResult.

// 2. Также, в классе добавим сеттер, получающий реализованный объект коллбека от кого-нибудь (в нашем случае от Активити), чтобы сообщить ему в будущем о результатах.

// 3. И описываем метод run, в котором собственно всё и выполняется.

```
public class ThreadDataStream extends Thread {

    public interface IDataStreamCallback {
        void dataResult(String result);
    }

    private IDataStreamCallback callback;

    public void setCallback(IDataStreamCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // выполнение сложных операций
    }
}
```

// 4. В нашей активити укажем, что мы наследуем интерфейс IDataStreamCallback. После этого АндроидСтудия будет ожидать, что вы реализуете метод интерфейса (подчеркнёт всё красным). Просто нажмите alt+enter и выберите "Имплементировать методы" и затем метод dataResult.

// 5. Создайте всю свою активность, а в методе коллбека укажите, что результат нужно запускать с помощью runOnUiThread.

// 6. Создайте экземпляр ThreadDataStream, укажите ему в качестве коллбека свою активити и запустите. Через некоторое время вы получите результат в main-потоке.

// 7. В методе onDestroy можно отписаться от результатов выполнения, если они ещё не готовы, а активность уже уничтожается.

```
public class ThreadActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
    implements ThreadDataStream.IDataStreamCallback {

private TextView textView;
private ThreadDataStream threadDataStream;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.thread_activity);

    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

    threadDataStream = new ThreadDataStream();
    threadDataStream.setCallback(ThreadActivity.this);
    threadDataStream.run();
}

@Override
public void dataResult(String result) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textView.setText(result);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (threadDataStream != null) {
        threadDataStream.setCallback(null);
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Вот и всё, удачного кодинга!

Answer (score 0):

`Handler` и `Callback` нужно создать в активности, фрагменте или где вызывается поток и передать в поток ссылку на него. Если создание происходит не в главном потоке, то нужно указать `Looper`.

```
// создаём Handler и обработчик сообщений в активности или фрагменте (где вызывается наш поток)
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper(), new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
        String text = (String) msg.obj;
           homeFragment.temperature.setText(text);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Запуск потока. Передаём ему ссылку на Handler и там записываем в поле.

```
ThreadDataStream threadDataStream = new ThreadDataStream(bluetoothSocket, handler);
```

В потоке используем

```
mHandler.obtainMessage(0, "asd").sendToTarget();
```